# libphonenumber, php and CI3 - trying to validate a phone number but not getting expected result

Tags: php, codeigniter, libphonenumber

I have a controller with the follow CI3 validation rule of a Japanese phone number:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line('create_user_validation_phone_label'), 'callback_phonenumber_check');
```

The callback method is currently as follows (trying to debug):

```
    public function phonenumber_check($str){
    $phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
    try{
        $phoneNumber    = $phoneUtil->parse($str, "JP");
        $isValid = $phoneUtil->isValidNumber($phoneNumber);
        var_dump($isValid);
        if ($isValid==TRUE){
            echo 'isValid is TRUE';
            var_dump($isValid);
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            echo 'isValid is FALSE';
            var_dump($isValid);
            return FALSE;
        }   
    }catch( \libphonenumber\NumberParseException $e){
        //var_dump($e);
        echo 'someother errTRUE';
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

For some reason, when I submit the form I get below even on with a phone number of '0362222229s' (not the non numeric at the end):

```
bool(true) bool(true) bool(true) bool(true)
```

Also, no idea why I get 4 x bool(true)

Any guidance appreciated.